# Static Block Links in Wrong Position / Size

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2

I have created a **static block** with the identifier **top_menu** and one with the identifier **footer_links** with different links than the previous block with the same identifier.

Why is the "Contact Us" link sitting lower than it should in the navigation bar, and why are the links "WHY CHOOSE US?", "FAQ" and "CONTACT US" sitting above row 2 (the existing links) at a smaller size without the hover property, when it should be in row 1 (to the left of the existing links)?

***Please see images***

Link to Store: https://cashino.kellyseye.com/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you manage it through cms block?

Comment: I have just added the static blocks by navigating to CMS > Static Blocks. The name and identifier of the block is identical to the previous block which displayed correctly. This can be seen at https://store.kellyseye.com/ - I just wanted to remove certain links for my new store view.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: hi @jordan, please mark as acceptance answer to the answer that solved your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have added your code in like below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/whychooseus/">Why Choose Us?</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/contacts/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which should be:

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/whychooseus/">Why Choose Us?</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://cashino.kellyseye.com/contacts/">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Replace your static block code with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though when you have added your block, you haven't added the correct HTML.

Looking at your code, you are missing a;

```
<div class="links">
```

Around your unordered list. There are a few ways you can do this.

1. Add it into the static block itself.
2. If you are calling getChildHtml('child') - wrap this in a div.
3. Or if you are using just XML use the arguments function.

Hope this helps.